# How to get RouteCollection from a request in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url-routing

This is my global.asax (Registering the route)

```
  routes.MapRoute("NewDatabase",
             "Server/{serverId}/Instances/{instanceId}/NewDatabase/",
             new { controller = "Server", action = "NewDatabase" }
             );

            routes.MapRoute(
           "Instance",
           "Server/{id}/Instances/{instanceId}/Databases",
           new { controller = "Server", action = "Databases", id = "id",instanceId="instanceId" }
           );

            routes.MapRoute(
           "Database",
           "Server/{id}/Instances",
           new { controller = "Server", action = "Instances", id = "id" }
           );
```

If `xyz.com/Server/12/Instance/1/NewDatabase` will be the reuested URL to server, 
`Server/{serverId}/Instances/{instanceId}/NewDatabase/` will be the matching pattern.
How can I know which  entry is matched for the above request ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

`RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(HttpContextBase)`

Comment: i got something from httpcontest. will update on my office hour

Comment: @kbvishnu really?

Answer (score 1):

Install the [RouteDebugger](http://nuget.org/packages/routedebugger) nuget package and enabled it in your web.config. This tells you which routes can be hit and why.

```
<add key="RouteDebugger:Enabled" value="true" />
```

All you have to do is navigate to your url. RouteDebugger will add route info to the bottom of your page.

Comment: is there any in-build method ?

Comment: @VeeKeyBee. Not that I know if. But it only takes minutes to set up the above. Is there a reason why you cannot?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for but you can create a custom route constraint which enables you to prevent a route from being matched unless some custom condition is matched.

You can implement Match method which returns a Boolean value. If you return false, the route associated with the constraint won’t match the browser request. This method has RouteValueDictionary so you can check route values from there.

see this url for more information -  http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-custom-route-constraint-cs